# VBA Loop throught text file and import into to different tables

Tags: vba, loops

My project is to open a text file and loop through the data, when the suitable data found we want the insert that line of data into a table. there are  four different type of data to insert into four different table.

Below is my example data I need to loop through, along with my code. the problems is my code did not pick any TRAN data and debug print it. thanks for reading and help is much appreciated.

```
$TRAN,001003659,0,2,0,2,2550,04/01/10,09:14:00,6
$PAYM,3,Credit Card,2800,2550,0,0,0
$ITEM,00006110,18,1,0,1275,A,,,4,0,0,1275,,0
$ITEM,00006110,18,1,0,1275,A,,,4,0,0,1275,,0
$NOSALE,001003660,04/01/10,09:18:34,6
$TRAN,001003661,23,9,3,13,7010,04/01/10,15:14:27,5
```

> ```
> Private Sub Command0_Click()
> Open "Sharp Sales\TRMSAVE01.txt" For Input As #1
> Dim TRAN As String
> TRAN = "%Tran%"
>
> Do Until EOF(1)
>
> Line Input #1, varTran
> Line Input #1, varPaym
> Line Input #1, varItem
> Line Input #1, varNosale
> strTran = Mid(varTran, 4, Len(varTran) - 10)
> strPaym = Mid(varPaym, 4, Len(varPaym) - 10)
> strItem = Mid(varItem, 4, Len(varItem) - 10)
> strNosale = Mid(varNosale, 4, Len(varNosale) - 10)
>
> If TRAN = varTran Then
> Debug.Print varTran
> DoCmd.RunSQL Transql = " Insert into Transaction (Tran ID, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, Date, Time, 6)Value  
> ('" & strTran & "', '" & strPaym & "', '" & strItem & "', '" & strNosale & "')"
>
> End If
>
> Loop
> Close #1
> End Sub
> ```

Answer (score 0):

`Line Input` will always return the next line!

Thus,  `Line Input #1, varNosale` will actually return your second $ITEM, not the $NOSALE line.

Then in the second loop, your first statement `Line Input #1, varTran` will read the 5th line, which is $NOSALE and not TRAN as you're checking!

The better approach would be something like this pseudo code:

```
Dim blnFirst As Boolean
blnFirst = True
Do Until EOF(1)
    Line Input strLine
    Select Case Left(strLine, 5)
        Case "$TRAN":
            If Not blnFirst Then
                Execute insert SQL here, using strTranID, strItemIds, etc.
            End If
            strTranID = ...
            strItemIds = ""
            blnFirst = False
        Case "$PAYM": strPayment = ...
        Case "$ITEM": strItemIds = strItemIds & ... 'maybe use an array here
        Case "$NOSA": strNoSale = ...
    End Select    
Loop
```